# ¿Cómo hacer que un marker recorra un polyline en Java?

Tags: java, android-studio, google-maps

Estoy trabajando en una app, similar a uber, didi, etc. Tengo un problema al momento de hacer las animaciones de los vehículos (que van desde punto A hasta punto B), encontré este código en Internet y funciona bastante bien:

```
public void animateMarker(final LatLng startPosition, final LatLng toPosition,final boolean hideMarke) {
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        final Marker m = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(startPosition)
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.bus2))
                .title("Camión"));
        final long start = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        Projection proj = map.getProjection();
        Point startPoint = proj.toScreenLocation(m.getPosition());
        final LatLng startLatLng = proj.fromScreenLocation(startPoint);
        final long duration = 5000;

        final Interpolator interpolator = new LinearInterpolator();

        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                long elapsed = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - start;
                float t = interpolator.getInterpolation((float) elapsed
                        / duration);
                double lng = t * toPosition.longitude + (1 - t)
                        * startLatLng.longitude;
                double lat = t * toPosition.latitude + (1 - t)
                        * startLatLng.latitude;
                m.setPosition(new LatLng(lat, lng));

                if (t < 1.0) {
                    // Post again 16ms later.
                    handler.postDelayed(this, 16);
                } else {
                    if (hideMarke) {
                        m.setVisible(false);
                    } else {
                        m.setVisible(true);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        markers.add(m);
    }
```

Tengo este método que se encarga de pasarle las posiciones de una lista con todas las coordenadas que requiero para los Polylines:

```
private void controlAnimaciones(List<LatLng> ruta) {
        for (int i=0; i<ruta.size()-1; i++) {
            if (i<ruta.size()) {
                animateMarker(ruta.get(i), ruta.get(i+1), false);
            }
        }
    }
```

Hace lo que esperaba que hiciera, si mueve el marcador de punto A hasta punto B, pero, solamente iterando la lista, no sé bien como explicarme, aparecen muchos marcadores que se mueven sólo desde un elemento de la lista al siguiente y posterior a esto se detienen. Lo que quiero hacer es lograr que un sólo marcador pueda moverse por todos los puntos de la lista, he estado intentando de algunas formas con el código que obtuve de internet, para tratar de entenderlo, pero no he tenido mucho éxito. ¿Cómo podría hacerlo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He hecho la misma pregunta en el foro en inglés y me han dado una respuesta perfecta, aquí el link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68049660/how-to-make-a-marker-traverse-a-polyline-in-java

Además, yo también había encontrado una manera alterna de resolver mi pregunta, la obtuve del siguiente link:
https://www.it-swarm-es.com/es/java/rotar-el-marcador-y-mover-la-animacion-en-el-mapa-como-uber-android/823870720/

Adjunto el código en específico que usé:

```
public void animateMarker(final List<LatLng> rutas) {
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        final Marker m = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(rutas.get(0))
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.bus2))
                .title("Camión"));

        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                if (currentPt < rutas.size()) {
                    //post again
                    Log.d("tess", "inside run ");
                    Location targetLocation = new Location(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                    targetLocation.setLatitude(rutas.get(currentPt).latitude);
                    targetLocation.setLongitude(rutas.get(currentPt).longitude);
                    animateMarkerNew(targetLocation, m);
                    handler.postDelayed(this, 3000);
                    currentPt++;
                } else {
                    Log.d("tess", "call back removed");
                    //removed callbacks
                    handler.removeCallbacks(this);
                }
            }
        }, 3000);
        markers_animations.add(m);
    }

    private void animateMarkerNew(final Location destination, final Marker marker) {
        if (marker != null) {

            final LatLng startPosition = marker.getPosition();
            final LatLng endPosition = new LatLng(destination.getLatitude(), destination.getLongitude());

            final float startRotation = marker.getRotation();
            final LatLngInterpolatorNew latLngInterpolator = new LatLngInterpolatorNew.LinearFixed();

            ValueAnimator valueAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0, 1);
            valueAnimator.setDuration(3000); // duration 3 second
            valueAnimator.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
            valueAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                    try {
                        float v = animation.getAnimatedFraction();
                        LatLng newPosition = latLngInterpolator.interpolate(v, startPosition, endPosition);
                        marker.setPosition(newPosition);
                        /*map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(new CameraPosition.Builder()
                                .target(newPosition)
                                .zoom(15.5f)
                                .build()));*/

                        //marker.setRotation(getBearing(startPosition, new LatLng(destination.getLatitude(), destination.getLongitude())));
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        //I don't care atm..
                    }
                }
            });
            valueAnimator.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    super.onAnimationEnd(animation);

                    // if (mMarker != null) {
                    // mMarker.remove();
                    // }
                    // mMarker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(endPosition).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.icon_car)));

                }
            });
            valueAnimator.start();
        }
    }

    private interface LatLngInterpolatorNew {
        LatLng interpolate(float fraction, LatLng a, LatLng b);

        class LinearFixed implements LatLngInterpolatorNew {
            @Override
            public LatLng interpolate(float fraction, LatLng a, LatLng b) {
                double lat = (b.latitude - a.latitude) * fraction + a.latitude;
                double lngDelta = b.longitude - a.longitude;
                // Take the shortest path across the 180th meridian.
                if (Math.abs(lngDelta) > 180) {
                    lngDelta -= Math.signum(lngDelta) * 360;
                }
                double lng = lngDelta * fraction + a.longitude;
                return new LatLng(lat, lng);
            }
        }
    }

    //Method for finding bearing between two points
    private float getBearing(LatLng begin, LatLng end) {
        double lat = Math.abs(begin.latitude - end.latitude);
        double lng = Math.abs(begin.longitude - end.longitude);

        if (begin.latitude < end.latitude && begin.longitude < end.longitude)
            return (float) (Math.toDegrees(Math.atan(lng / lat)));
        else if (begin.latitude >= end.latitude && begin.longitude < end.longitude)
            return (float) ((90 - Math.toDegrees(Math.atan(lng / lat))) + 90);
        else if (begin.latitude >= end.latitude && begin.longitude >= end.longitude)
            return (float) (Math.toDegrees(Math.atan(lng / lat)) + 180);
        else if (begin.latitude < end.latitude && begin.longitude >= end.longitude)
            return (float) ((90 - Math.toDegrees(Math.atan(lng / lat))) + 270);
        return -1;
    }
```